# Regex to match everything but a combination of characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to match all characters in a string except for the #*# pattern. The regex I have below works for cases such as match1 below, but it will also match #'s or *'s that are not in the #*# pattern as seen in match2 below and fail because of that. How can I fix the below regex to match #*# if they appear together?

```
var string1 = 'Hello#*#World#*#Some other string#*#false'
var string2 = 'Hello#*#World#*#Some #other #string#*#false'
// This would match
var match1 = string1.match(/^([^#*#]+)#\*#([^#*#]+)#\*#([^#*#]+)#\*#([^#*#]+)$/);  
// This would no longer match since it matches other #'s that are not in a #*# pattern
var match2 = string2.match(/^([^#*#]+)#\*#([^#*#]+)#\*#([^#*#]+)#\*#([^#*#]+)$/);
```

Also the match should match the whole words between the pattern. So for match1 it would be

```
[ 'Hello#*#World#*#Some other string#*#false',
  'Hello',
  'World',
  'Some other string',
  'false',
  index: 0,
  input: 'Hello#*#World#*#Some other string#*#false',
  groups: undefined ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try  this.**

```js
var string1 = 'Hello#*#World#*#Some other string#*#false'
var string2 = 'Hello#*#World#*#Some #other #string#*#false'
// This would match
var match1 = string1.match(/[^(#\*#)]+/g);  

var match2 = string2.match(/[^(#\*#)]+/g);

console.log(match1);
console.log(match2);
```

Comment: I updated my question because I meant to ask about matching the full words in between the #*# instead of each unique character. See the example match in my question

Comment: @Adrian updated answer. if it help you can select it as correct answer :p anyways happy to help :)

Comment: Thank you this is perfect! I had something similar at one point but without the global modifier